# I need to position a popup box

Tags: vbscript, popup, position, messagebox, msgbox

I need to position the popup boxes towards the top right corner but just below the close minimize and maximize buttons.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Do

   set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
for each oResult in oResults
   iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

while (1)
  set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
  for each oResult in oResults
    iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
    bCharging = oResult.Charging
  next
  iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100
  if bCharging and (iPercent > 80) Then msgbox "Battery is charged now more than 80%. Please stop charging for optimal battery life."
  if bCharging and (iPercent < 20) Then msgbox "Battery is discharging and is below 20%. Please switch on charging immediately."

if bcharging then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Charging", 1, "Charging status"
else
end if
if not bcharging then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Not charging", 1, "Charging status"
end if
wend
WScript.Quit 1
    WScript.Sleep 0
Loop
```

I've tried testing different scripts to position it, but they never work.

Comment: A script that loops with a constantly updating display cannot be done efficiently or elegantly in VBScript. Rewrite it as an HTA to get the desired result. I'll post an example soon.

Comment: The percent calculation should be `iPercent = Int(iRemaining/iFull * 100)`

Comment: Did you look at the script I posted?

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to be written as an HTA in order to have a display that remains on screen, in a desired position, and updates on an interval.

See [Battery.hta](https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/blob/main/HTA-misc/Battery.hta) for an example.